# Add multiple markers on map on ionic 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-maps-markers

Does anyone know how to edit the code to show multiple markers on the map?

```
DisplayMap(){

  const location = new google.maps.LatLng('1.330110','103.854800');

  const options = {
    center:location,
    zoom:10,
    streetViewControl:false,
    mapTypeId:'satellite'

  };

  const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement,options);

  this.addMarker(location,map);
}


addMarker(position,map){
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position,
    map
  });
}
```

Comment: you need to specify three lat and lon and then call your `addMarker()`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you will be adding more and more markers on the map using a JSON file in the future. So this answer can stay here for when you need it.

First, if you are using this in a .NET project you can call a method from the controller side and use the returned data to add markers on the map;

> But remember you must add jQuery into the page before using ajax to be able to use
>   AJAX

```
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:'ControllerName/ActionName', // or you could specify an unique route from the routeconfig and use it
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data){
    // the data will be your json file, to use it in an array format
    // use JSON.parse(data)
    let resultArray = JSON.parse(data);
        for(let i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(resultArray[i].LATITUDE,
                      resultArray[i].LONGITUDE),
                  map: map
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And your controller should look like this;

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAgencies()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"yourJsonFilePath"))
    {
        return Json(reader.ReadToEnd(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Or you could use `fetch` method that can be used without needing jQuery;

```
fetch(jsonUrl).then(function (response) {
        response.json().then(function (results) {
        for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(results[i].LATITUDE,
                      results[i].LONGITUDE),
                  map: map
            });
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To add another marker, first create a second location `const location2 = google.maps.LatLng('1.328120', '103.849639')` and then add a new marker for that location `this.addMarker(location2, map)`. Please see the code below:

```
DisplayMap() {

    const location = new google.maps.LatLng('1.330110', '103.854800');

    const options = {
        center: location,
        zoom: 10,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'

    };

    const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, options);

    this.addMarker(location, map);

    // this is a new, 2nd location
    const location2 = google.maps.LatLng('1.328120', '103.849639');

    // add 2nd marker for location2
    this.addMarker(location2, map);
}


addMarker(position, map) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position,
        map
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!